# Do eclipses have an effect on the efficacy of potions?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, potions, astronomy

In Harry Potter, when you cook a potion during an eclipse, either lunar or solar, would that affect the strength of a potion like in the Switch game, *Breath of the Wild*, when a blood moon approaches just before the reset happens and you cook on a pot?

After playing *Breath of the Wild* a lot it got me wondering if in the Harry Potter series, when eclipses happen, if the strengths of potions or even certain spells would be altered during an eclipse phase and to what effect that would entail if you were doing one?

It has been sort of talked about on werewolves but not on effects of potions/spells.

Comment: Eclipses are super cool, so a wizard might get distracted, and make a worse potion.

Answer (score 6):

### There doesn’t seem to be any magic said to be affected by eclipses.

There’s absolutely no mention of what effect an eclipse would have on any type of magic in the books. The word “eclipse” only is used twice in the books, both referring to something being “eclipsed” metaphorically, rather than referring to the actual astronomical event.

#### There are no known spells affected by the moon - eclipses shouldn’t affect them.

There are no spells mentioned in the books that are affected by moon phase. Since spells seem to work entirely independent of the moon, it’s highly unlikely that an eclipse would affect the vast majority of spells - almost certainly not any of the ones mentioned in the books.

#### Sometimes moon phase matters but it’s unclear what an eclipse would do.

At least one ingredient in one potion needs to be picked at the full moon.

> “Well, as the fluxweed has got to be picked at the full moon and the lacewings have got to be stewed for twenty-one days … I’d say it’d be ready in about a month, if we can get all the ingredients.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 10 (The Rogue Bludger)*</sup></sub>

However, it’s unclear if an eclipse would make a difference, since the moon’s phase would still be full despite the eclipse. There’s nothing that could lead us to a logical conclusion to what effect an eclipse would have if any.

There also may be a cure for spattergroit that’s dependent on moon phase, but since the portrait who suggested it was also unable to tell freckles from a disease, this isn’t necessarily a real cure.

> “– the only remedy is to take the liver of a toad, bind it tight about your throat, stand naked at the full moon in a barrel of eels’ eyes –’
>   ‘I have not got spattergroit!’
>
> ‘But the unsightly blemishes upon your visage, young master –’
>
> ‘They’re freckles!’ said Ron furiously. ‘Now get back in your own picture and leave me alone!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 23 (Christmas on the Closed Ward)*</sup></sub>

However, again, there’s nothing that indicates what effect an eclipse would have (and this may not even be a working cure).